# No right border when using float right for div containing span?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I want to have some items with border on the right side of the page. But the border is only visible to the top, left and bottom, but not to the right in webkit browsers. I have tested on Google Chrome for Windows, Safari on iPhone and Chrome on Android. Firefox and IE, however, shows a border on all four sides like I expect.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <span class="wrapper">
        <span>no right border</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    float: right
}

.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

See live example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/3t7zW/2/

Is this a known bug in webkit or do I have to add something to the css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it has to do with it being inline. If you add `display:block` (or `display: inline-block`) to `.wrapper`, the border will show up.

Comment: Correct answer here. Known bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=58806 or https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=57441

Comment: Thanks kalley for the answer and Pete for the research. `inline-block` works as I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

If you take out the extra span tags around 'no right border', there is in fact a right border.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZWWct/

You can also just simplify your css to:

`.wrapper {
  float:right;
  border: 1px solid black;
}`